# $http angularjs calls not executing from Mobile Device with Worklight

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I don't know if this is really worklight specific.  But on ios/mobile devices, this `$http` call is not executing (or at least doesn't seem like it).

I don't reach the `success` point or the `error` point.  When monitoring with network traffic, I don't see the request being made.  Do you see the issue here, is it worklight, angular?

I was trying to add `scope.apply` and also changing the request parameters.  I tried similar code with an jquery/ajax but got similar results.

Also, when I test this in a desktop-browser (non-mobile) context, the call works fine.  Do you see what might correct the `$http` call from not executing?

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var httplogout = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://server.com/logout',
        data: {},
        timeout: 8000
    }).then(function(data) {        
        deferred.resolve();
    }, function(err) {             
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise();
};

$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        httplogout().then(function() {        
            WL.Logger.debug('Done');
        });
    });
    }, 
1);
```

Comment: try using $hhtp.post(url) . also whats up with $timeout and the $apply(); you don't need that, you are inside angulars digest cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a cross domain request and should probably be using `$http.jsonp` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp. You can see whether this is the problem by looking at the developer console and you should see a cross domain exception associated with the HTTP request

You can look at this page for some additional information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#xdomainsec_secconcernswebapiwg but basically, you should also ensure that your server has the correct headers set to allow cross domain requests and deals with the JSONP callback.

Here is some Node.js/Express code to set these headers on a response (and also deal with the JSONP callback)

```
function sendResponse(req, res, data) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers && req.headers.origin ? req.headers.origin : '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    if (req.query.callback) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
        var response = req.query.callback + '(' +
            JSON.stringify(data) +
            ');';
        res.send(response);
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(data);
    }
}
```

You should also implement the OPTIONS HTTP request (here some Node.js/Express code)

```
app.options('*',
    function(req, res) {
        sendResponse(req, res, {});
    });
```

Comment: Are all worklight mobile device requests cross domain? I dont' see a cross domain exception.  there is no error.

Comment: It looks like it could be mobile related (sort of related to cordova, phonegap).  It seemed like a strange error because I couldn't see that code execute.

Comment: Worklight is basically Cordova with IBM stuff wrapped around it. The answer is - yes - all requests to an external server will be considered cross-domain requests because your UI pages are being served up from a file:// URL

Comment: I guess under the covers, ibm is hiding the cross domain enablement with its worklight adapter calls.  In this case, I am making a vanilla ajax request.  Is jsonp the only way to implement this cross domain approach?